# req.body is always an empty object

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm doing a React App + Express server,

I want to get in a route /info in my server all the infos from a form in a client,

But when I console log "req.body" in the server, I always get an empty object (see Express code below),

I tried to use body-parser but nothing changes, I don't see where's the issue,

Can somebody help me please ?

React code :

```
async function getResults(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const info = {
      minimumPrice,
      maximumPrice
    };

    console.log("info ", info);

    try {
      const data = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/info", info);
      console.log("data ", data);

      setResults(data.data);
      console.log("results ", data.data);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }

<form onSubmit={getResults} autoComplete="off" method="get">
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="input-field col s12">
                    <input
                      id="minimum-price"
                      type="number"
                      name="minimumPrice"
                      placeholder="Entrez votre prix minimum"
                      value={minimumPrice}
                      onChange={e => setMinimumPrice(e.target.value)}
                      style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent !important" }}
                      required
                    />
                    <label htmlFor="email">Prix minimum</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="input-field col s12">
                    <input
                      id="maximum-price"
                      type="number"
                      name="maximumPrice"
                      placeholder="Entrez votre prix maximum"
                      value={maximumPrice}
                      onChange={e => setMaximumPrice(e.target.value)}
                      style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent !important" }}
                      required
                    />
                    <label htmlFor="email">Prix maximum</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col s12" style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                    <button
                      className="btn waves-effect waves-light"
                      type="submit"
                      name="action"
                    >
                      Rechercher
                      <i className="material-icons right">send</i>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
```

Express code :

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const leboncoin = require("leboncoin-api");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");


app.use(cors());
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  })
);
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/info", (req, res) => {
  console.log("body ", req.body); <---------- ALWAYS AN EMPTY OBJECT
}
```

Comment: You're not POSTing anything or providing a body.  You're doing a GET and sending query parameters (`req.query`).

Comment: GET requests don't send a body.  The body comes with POST or PUT.  GET requests can send parameters in the URL query string which would be in `req.query`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making a get request with axios. The parameters sent with get request are available in req.query.

Parameters passed with **post** request are received in req.body.